# How to provide a service using request information and dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently looking into developing an application using asp netcore 1.0.

The different versions of dependency injection are pointed out [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html). To me it appears the correct choice for my case would be to have a scoped instance.

What i am trying to do is register an interface to delegate calls to another web api.

Interface:

```
public interface IControlCenterRestClient
{
    List<ControlCenter> GetAll();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class ControlCenterRestClient : RestClientBase, IControlCenterRestClient
{
    public ControlCenterRestClient(string baseUrl, string user, string password) : base(baseUrl, user, password)
    {
    }

    public List<ControlCenter> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<ControlCenter>();
    }
}
```

Common base class:

```
public abstract class RestClientBase
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; }

    public string User { get; }

    public string Password { get; }

    protected RestClientBase(string baseUrl, string user, string password)
    {
        BaseUrl = baseUrl;
        User = user;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

### My issue:

Now in order to provide this service within netcore controllers as `IControlCenterRestClient`, i need to construct objects using current request information (logged in user -> obtain his user and password and delegate it to construct an appropriate instance)

Since i didn't find a similar issue on SO yet, nor any docs for my particular case i thought i'd share the solution for googlers (I figured it out while typing this question).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can provide services which require HttpContext based information:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IControlCenterRestClient>(ControlCenterFactory);
    }

    private static IControlCenterRestClient ControlCenterFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var http = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        // todo: use data obtained from http.HttpContext.User
        return new ControlCenterData();
    }
```